# printBackward recursion doesn't print first element of array when using operator ++

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I wanna print an integer array backward and detect that when using ++ instead of "startPos + 1" result comes to lose the first element of array. I debugged to understand the problem, but the recursion works so strange. Can you explain what the problem is? Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void printBackward(const int[], const int size, int startPosition);

int main(void)
{
    const int a[SIZE] = {1,3,5,7,9,10,13,15,17,19};
    printBackward(a,SIZE,0);
    puts("");
}
void printBackward(const int a[SIZE], const int size, int startPos)
{
    if(startPos < size)
    {
        printBackward(a,size,++startPos); // work wrongly with ++startPos
                //printBackward(a,size,startPos + 1); // work properly
        printf_s("%4d",a[startPos]);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `startPos++` instead

Comment: @RedAlert That would result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `startPos + 1` to the function does not change the value of `startPos`. However, `++startPos` actually increments the value of `startPos`. The two are not interchangeable.